# Show that if $\int_0^1 h(x)\cos(n \pi x)dx=0$, $n=1,2,\ldots$, then $h(x)$ is constant.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Show that if $\int_0^1 h(x)\cos(n \pi x)dx=0$, $n=1,2,\ldots$, then $h(x)$ is constant.

I know that if the index $n$ starts with zero then $h(x)$ is a zero function since in that case the system of function $\{\cos(n \pi x)\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is an complete orthormal system in $L_2$. However, in the question the system of function is $\{\cos(n \pi x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and not a complete system.

Comment: But you're not supposed to show that $h$ is the zero function, you're supposed to show that is is a constant function. And in the complete, orthonormal system $\{\cos(n \pi x)\}_{n=0}^\infty$, the constant functions are spanned by...?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already know $h$ is zero if the statement was true for $n=0$ too, you can just define $\tilde{h}=h-\int h$. You obtain $\tilde{h}=0$, or $h=\int h$.